# How to get the value of the first xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a question about LINQ in C#. I have to read out some values of a xml file.
This is the xml structure:

```
<section id="Decission-Tree">
  <stelle id="Test1">
    <h>Test1<translation lang="en">Test1</translation></h>
    <abstract>Test1<translation lang="en">Test1</translation></abstract>
    <import name="C:\Users\halbhelo\Documents\4 CAD\PKG\Template\man\dummy.txt" />
  </stelle>
</section>
```

I want the value of the h element. With my Code I get the result Test1Test1 because I also get the value of the element translation which is a element from h.

```
        var stellen = from section in xdocument.Descendants("section").Elements("stelle")
                       where section.Attribute("id").Value == "Test1"
                       select section;

        foreach (XElement stelle in stellen)
        {
            string result = stelle.Element("h").Value;
        }
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This XML structure is **incorrect**. The value and nested tag cant be together. It should be something like this: `<h><actual>Test1</actual><translation lang="en">Test1</translation></h>`

Comment: You have a `translation` node inside `h`, `<h>Test1<translation lang="en">Test1</translation></h>`

Comment: Your <h> contains two XML nodes, The first of type TEXT ("Test1") and the second of type ELEMENT (containing another TEXT node, also with a value of "Test1"). The property .Value returns the text from all TEXT nodes within a context. This is why the <h>.Value returns 'Test1 Test1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using your code, and getting the value of `FirstNode`, by replacing
this

```
string result = stelle.Element("h").Value;
```

By

```
string result = stelle.Element("h").FirstNode.ToString();
```

**Result**

```
Test1
```

I hope this helps you out.